# Iterate over a list, to check if character is present, using a for loop. If present, put character into a new list at that same spot

Tags: python, string, list, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to accomplish 2 things here.  First, I need to check a list, to see if a particular character is present on the list.

If the character is in the list, then I'd want to put that character into a separate list at the same exact spot in the index, and if it's not present, the list would just have a null in whatever spots don't have that letter.  So hypothetically in the example below, if I'm checking for the letter L, I'd want to return a list that reads `word2 = ['','','L','L','']`.

I've been trying this with a for loop, but I can't seem to return what I'm looking for.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks very much!

```
letter = 'L'  
word = ['H','E','L','L','O']  
word2 = []  

for i in word:  
     if letter in word:
```

Comment: I've read your comment on another answer of mine, and I've edit mine to answer about "how to check again multiple letters" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
letter = 'L'
word = ['H','E','L','L','O']
word2 = [w if w == letter else '' for w in word]
word2
```

output:

```
['', '', 'L', 'L', '']
```

or you can use a simple `for` loop:

```
word2 = []
for w in word:  
    if w  == letter:
        word2.append(letter)
    else:
        word2.append('')
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response!  exactly what i needed!

Comment: Ahh, just one more question...I noticed that while looping through, if the variable Letter changes, and it's also in the list: word, the loop will only display the most recent letter that's found.  So if someone first has letter = 'L', it'll display ['','','L','L',''].  but when Letter is changed to 'O', that loop is setting the two L's back to null.  I tried using:
word2 = [w if w == guess and w == '' else '' for w in word]
but that doesn't seem to be doing it, i just keep getting nulls back

Comment: yes, if the letter is changing then also the output is changing, so you want to change the letter? and also to keep the previous letters from `word2`?

Comment: yes exactly.  basically, i'm trying to give the user several attempts to guess the letters in a word.  i want to keep the previous output, and then print what they've guessed until that point.

Comment: @Peter `word2  = [w if  w == w2 or letter == w  else '' for w, w2 in zip(word, word2) ]` you could use this, but you have to define word2 at the beginning as `word2 = ['']*len(word)`

Comment: thanks again!  sorry to bother you, just had a general question, any particular advice for learning as much and efficiently as possible?  i've been watching these coding tutorials and now i've just been trying to do some exercises/projects (i've been told to just get at it and that's how to get better).

Comment: @Peter I was starting with this https://www.coursera.org/learn/interactive-python-1 I hope it can help you

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to check char equality, you may iterate over the chars of the word, and it equal to the specific letter : keep it, else put a empty char

```
for word_letter in word:
    if word_letter == letter:
        word2.append(word_letter)
    else:
        word2.append("")
```

---

Inline the `if` inside the `append`

```
for word_letter in word:
    word2.append(word_letter if word_letter == letter else "")
```

Inline the `for` into a list comprehension

```
word2 = [word_letter if word_letter == letter else "" for word_letter in word]
```

---

## Guess the word game

If you want the user to guess the word, you may need to check against multiple letters, and not once, for that store the letters in a list, and instead of checking equality, check for inclusion in the list of tries

```
tries = []
word = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']
word2 = [word_letter if word_letter in tries else "" for word_letter in word]

while "" in word2:  # a letter is still empty
    letter = input("Try a letter :")
    tries.append(letter)
    word2 = [word_letter if word_letter in tries else "" for word_letter in word]
    print("Word is now", word2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
letter = 'L'  
word = ['H','E','L','L','O']  

indices = [i for i, w in enumerate(word) if w == letter]
new_word = [''] * len(word)
for i in indices:
  new_word[i] = letter
print(new_word)
```

**Another simple solution using `lambda`:**

```
letter = 'L'  
word = ['H','E','L','L','O']
new_word = map(lambda w: letter if w == letter else '', word)
print(new_word)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a reminder that in Python strings are iterable and if you don't really need a list of characters you could do:

```
letter = 'L'
word = 'HELLO'

word2 = ''.join(c if c == letter else ' ' for c in word)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Python, you should avoid thinking in terms of index.  Approach the problem from the perspective of applying a transformation to elements of a list to obtain another.  This is what list comprehensions are for.

```
def keepL(letter): return letter if letter == "L" else ""

word2 = [ keepL(letter) for letter in word ]
```

There are a slew of other tricks you can use to process strings such as multiplication by a number to repeat a string (including zero times) and treating bookeans (comparison results) as 0 or 1.

Combining these, your list comprehension can do the job without defining a function (in this particular case):

```
word2 = [ letter*(letter=="L") for letter in word ]
```

*multiplies the letter by 1 or zero depending on whether it's an 'L' or not.*